# Android Uri method normalizeScheme causes crash

Tags: java, android, uri

The Android Uri.normaliseScheme() method always crashes.
It doesn't even throw an exception. I have tried many different versions of the below code. What am I doing wrong?

```
Uri tableUri = Uri.parse("content://fake.company.app/TableName");
Log.d(TAG, "Table URI: "+tableUri);
try
{
    if (tableUri != null)
    {
        tableUri = tableUri.normalizeScheme();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Basically I have determined that normaliseScheme is the culprit (by removing code, a line at a time). When normalizeScheme is entered my app crashes. I don't even get any information in LogCat.

If I only keep the first 2 lines it runs fine and I get this log message:
Table URI: content://fake.company.app/TableName

Comment: If it doesn't throw an exception, what do you mean by "crashes"

Comment: By "crashes" I mean that I run the app on my phone and at the point it reaches normalizeScheme the screen goes black. I have to wait a few seconds and then Android pops open a dialog saying "Unfortunately, the process fake.company.app has stopped." which only has an "OK" button on it. I press the "OK" button and it returns to the Android home screen.

Comment: Add Logcat stacktrace of the exception

Comment: There isn't any exception. The app crashes and LogCat says "<no entries>". Maybe I should also mention that I am programming directly on a tablet using AIDE.

Comment: I still don't get "the app crashes".  Exactly what happens?

Comment: normalizeScheme() was added in API 16, thus you have to check if the devices uses an API higher or equal to that, otherwise that method will not be found in the Uri class and the application will crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that seems to succeed is to do the work myself, by using the String toLowerCase method:

```
String uriStr = "content://fake.company.app/TableName";
Uri tableUri = Uri.parse(uriStr.toLowerCase());
```